# The most important trait for puzzling?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I was wondering what the most important trait for a puzzle creator and/or solver was. I think I've found the answer, but I could be wrong. I thought about it, deconstructed it, put it back together a different way and took it apart again.

In the end, I'm fairly sure that trait is ____________... what, you thought I'd just tell you? No, I worked too hard to figure it out. You'll need to find it yourself. I wrote it down, but it might be hard to read:

---

[image]

---

That's it, 12 tiles. But can you find the hidden trait written on them? It won't be easy. You'll know you've found it when you find a 12 letter word. Good luck!

Hint:

> To sort one set, you'll need to sort the other.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Building on rand al'thor's and DooplissForce's answers:

Rearrange the tiles so the blue shapes match up:

> [image]
>  This says "BLAISE", which implies Blaise de Vigenère, meaning we'll probably have to use the Vigenère cipher somewhere.

Rearrange the tiles so the red shapes match up:

> [image]
>  Which spells DANGER. Perhaps the Vigenère key is DANGER?

Another observation:

> Each of the twelve squares has one capital letter and one lowercase letter. That makes 12 capitals and 12 lower-case letters. I recorded the pairs of letters e.g. U and w, A and f. That gives us:
>   `UACOIWQSKGEM` 
>   `wfrexjakzgry`

Given the clue "To sort one set, you have to sort the other":

> Notice that the lower-case letters have two 'r's, but the capital have no repeats.  That suggests that we should sort by the capitals. Once I started to sort the capitals, I notice that they are regularly spaced, 'A C E G I...', which indicates that I'm on the right path.
>  The sorted letters are now:
>   `ACEGIKMOQSUW` 
>   `frrgxzyeakwj`

Taking the lower-case letters:

> Use 'DANGER' as a Vigenère key on them

Resulting in:

> creativeness!

Comment: Ay well done! :)

Answer (score 7):

(Partial answer)

Adding onto rand al'thor's answer, I rearranged them so all the *blue* shapes matched up:

> [image]
>  This says "BLAISE", which implies Blaise de Vigenère, meaning we'll probably have to use the Vigenère cipher somewhere.

Stealing from rand, the red shapes make:

> [image]
>  Which spells DANGER. Perhaps the Vigenère key is DANGER?

Another observation:

> Each of the twelve squares has one capital letter and one lowercase letter. Since there are thus twelve of each, and the code we're looking for has twelve letters, I don't think this is a coincidence. I tried using DANGER as a Vigenère key for the strings `UACOIWQSKGEM`, `wfrexjakzgry`, `CWGIASUMQKEO`, and `rjgxfkwyazre`, the strings gotten when you take the capital/lowercase letters going left to right, top to bottom, in each picture, and got:
>  `UACOIWQSKGEM -> RAPIEFNSXAAV`
>  `wfrexjakzgry -> tfeytsxkmanh`
>  `CWGIASUMQKEO -> ZWTCWBRMDEAX`
>  `rjgxfkwyazre -> ojtrbttyntnn`
>  i.e., nothing intelligible.

Comment: Ah, looks like we were both doing the same thing at the same time :-)

Comment: To sort one set, you need to sort the other.

Comment: The capital letters "UACOIWQSKGEM"  are unique, and skip two places each time (e.g. A C E G....)

Comment: I'm guessing "creativeness" but am yet to prove it!

Comment: Yay! My first solution!

Comment: @Donnelle You should type that up as an answer. For all I know you are, but if you aren't, you should be.

Comment: But I didn't do the puzzle part...

Comment: @Donnelle You were the first to the last step. That's enough to pitch in an answer. Just write out your thought process. You can refer back to other people's answers; I see it all the time.

Answer (score 6):

*Partial answer*

Rearrange the twelve squares so that all the *red* shapes match up:

> [image]
>
>  They seem to spell out DANGER.

Then do the same for the *blue* shapes:

> [image]
>
>  They seem to spell out BLAISE.

Note that the sentence in the OP "*I thought about it, deconstructed it, put it back together a different way and took it apart again.*" is a hint telling us what to do here.

Sadly, [rearranging these letters](http://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=dangerblaise&t=1000&a=n) doesn't seem to give anything useful. Perhaps the twelve-letter word we seek is

> DANGERBLAISE!

Comment: The random letters seem to suggest an imgur link

Comment: Small nudge: neither set has a C in it.

Comment: @qwertyu Danger Blaise?

Comment: *nods head yes* You're on the right track.

Comment: @qwerty The only other possibility I could think of was "Danler Blaise", but neither of those seems to anagram to anything useful. Is there some superhero called Danger Blaise, perhaps?

Comment: Blaise is a first name. Had I given the last name, you'd be much closer.

Comment: @qwertyu63 Pascal?

Comment: Right, I immediately thought "Blaise" -> "Pascal", but "Pascal danger" isn't much help either.

Comment: Right country, wrong man.

Comment: [Ohhhhh...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_de_Vigen%C3%A8re)